# Drawing an SVG line diagonally across its containing DIV (and maintaining as DIV resized)

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I am trying to draw an SVG line diagonally across a div like this:

[image]

I can create a div with an SVG line inside:

```
<div id="my_div" class="rectangle">
    <svg id="my_line" width='100%' height='100%' viewBox='0 0 2000 2000' preserveAspectRatio='none'><line style='red; stroke-width:2' /></svg>
</div>
```

Since I can resize the containing rectangle div, I need the SVG line to move *with* the rectangle div as it's resized, always touching the top left and bottom right corners.

I try to use getBoundingClientRect to set the line positions:

```
var rect_box = document.getElementById("my_div").getBoundingClientRect();

$("#my_line").attr("x1", rect_box.left)
$("#my_line").attr("y1", rect_box.top)
$("#my_line").attr("x2", rect_box.right)
$("#my_line").attr("y2", rect_box.bottom)
```

But this doesn't work. Is there a way to set the viewBox, or apply CSS, such that the SVG line always remains fixed across the diagonal of its containing div?

**Note**: There's also [this](https://codepen.io/nkemcels/pen/XWbgaXB?editors=1100) approach that uses CSS clip path, and it remains fixed to its corners during resizing, but the thickness of the line changes as it's resized. I need the line thickness to remain constant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No javascript required.

```css
#my_div {
  outline: 1px solid;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div id="my_div">
  <svg width='100%' height='100%' viewBox='0 0 100 100' preserveAspectRatio='none'>
       <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="100" y2="100" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke" stroke="red" />
    </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Beautiful, works perfectly. Thank you. I thought the x2 and y2 values would have prevented the length from changing, but they resize perfectly.

Comment: Thanks, the `vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke` was what I was missing to keep the line a consistent width no matter the dimension.